# Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.1.1) questions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have recently downloaded the Facebook PHP SDK to try and post to a Facebook user's wall.

My Facebook user is currently logged in but has not used my app.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
 // user is logged in

} else {
 // user is not logged in
   $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('next' => 'http://localhost.com/php-sdk/examples/example.php'));
   header("Location: $url");
}
```

I've noticed that it redirects me to a page where it requires me to log into the app, which is kinda weird as this is the first time i have seen this behavior, it says "You are logging into DummyFBApp as User" at the bottom. Whenever i try to use other fb apps it only ask me for permissions to access my information, post, etc.

Is it possible to skip this "login" and only show the dialog whether to allow the app to post to the user wall?

Comment: Yes, here's a screenshot. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/59/96444731.png/

Comment: Is this application in sandbox mode?

Comment: if your referring to the script, yes, i have it locally; if your referring to my registered fb app, DummyFBApp, I dont know what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours is server side instead of using the JS SDK, but take a look anyway: [Facebook permission dialog (JavaScript sdk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846155/facebook-permission-dialog-javascript-sdk) .

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that is the new auth dialog. There should be an option under settings -> advanced in the Facebook app setup that allows you to turn it off for the time being.